# Doctrine join query access problem

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine

i have two tables pages and page_desc and have a relation

$this->hasMany('Model_PagesDesc as PageDesc', array(
         'local' => 'id',
         'foreign' => 'pages_id'));

i have a query

```
return Doctrine_Query::create()
                 ->select('m.*, d.*')
                 ->from('Model_Pages m')
                 ->leftJoin('m.PageDesc d')
                 ->execute();
```

NOW WHEN QUERY EXECUTES. iN VIEW WHEN I TRY TO GET FIELD VALUE OF SCEOND TABLE IT RETURNS SOME INTEGER INSTEAD OF ACUAL VALUE IN FIELD

```
<?php echo $pages->PageDesc->content;?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If youre using `hasMany` then you should `Model_Pages::PagesDesc` will be a `Doctrine_Collection` not a `Model_PagesDesc` instance. Im not sure but i would assume that the default behavior of the collection is to return the `count` of elements in the collection when converted to string, thus the integer. You need to either loop over the collection or get a specific item.

```
<?php echo $pages->PageDesc->getFirst()->content; ?>
```

OR

```
<?php foreach($pages->PageDesc as $desc): ?>
  <?php echo $desc->content; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Or you could write a custom collection for this model that returns concat of the `content` fields for every element in the collection.

However it seemdsthat a page shouldnt really have more than one description should it? You might want to consider using a 1-1 relation or just making the description a column on your page model.